# How does clipboard work with deep dynamic linking

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, branch.io

I realized alot of the libraries like firebase dynamic link and branch.io, dynamic link basically copies url to the clipboard and reads it once the app is opened. I realized that the ios 15 and 16 have the copy clipboard privacy and I was wondering if this will not work for any of the dynamic links anymore.